# Change Time Format in Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com

How do I change the time format in outlook.com?  By default, it is 24 hour format, but I'd like to change it to 12 hour format. There doesn't seem to be any option to change it in the settings menu

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a missing settings - Please have a look at the [discussion on Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/hotmail-wlsettings/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-windows-hotmail/3aa7c254-f36d-40bd-a713-380e701f2395?msgId=781b8afa-05e7-456e-9db7-4b944c98c729)